# trouble registering python graphics shapes with a for loop

Tags: python, image, shapes

I'm working with images in the python turtle graphics module and I'd like to save space by registering all my shapes (gif images) at once in a FOR loop that takes the filenames of all images in a subfolder I have (assets)

It was working for the first 10 files (filenames 1-10) when I used range(1,11) but I'd like to make it more comprehensive and adaptive.

```
import turtle
import os
from turtle import Turtle,Screen
import random
import math

logoTurtle = turtle.Turtle()
screen = Screen()
screen.screensize(800, 800)
screen.register_shape("assets/logo.gif")

#problem starts here

files = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','j','q','k','spade','heart','diamond','club']
for fileNames in files:
    screen.register_shape('"assets/"'+fileNames+'.gif"')
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting " Bad arguments for register_shape."

Comment: why the `'"` (single quote followed by double quote)? `screen.register_shape("assets/"+fileNames+".gif")` should work.

Comment: @Stuart that did it, cheers